# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 : YGConfig

Tags: react-native-ios

I have tried every possible solution online around this error.

Almost been a week now, still keep on hopping into the same thing while building a React Native iOS app.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "YGConfig::YGConfig(int (*)(YGConfig*, YGNode*, YGLogLevel, char const*, void*))", referenced from:
      _YGConfigNew in libyoga.a(Yoga.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me resolve this.